# UITableView - registerClass with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, registerclass

Is anyone else having an issue using the `tableView.registerClass` method with Swift?

It no longer comes in code completion for me (nor can I use it if manually typed) but it is still in the headers...

[image: Code Completion]

[image: UITableView headers]

Answer (score 112, accepted):

It works for me perfectly.

```
self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Exactly as I have it above.

Comment: This is crazy...a tableView in Playground works fine. Uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode...but to no avail. :-(

Comment: Can you show a little more code? How you declare the table view, class etc.

Comment: This corrected itself with an install of Xcode beta **6** this morning. Marking yours as correct answer because, well, the code is correct.

Comment: Why would Swift make this UITableViewCell.self instead of something like UITableViewCell.class?

Comment: It is renamed to self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

Answer (score 14):

**For Swift 2.2 Register For Default Cell From Class**

```
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DefaultCell")
```

**For Swift 3.0 Register For Default Cell From Class**

```
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DefaultCell")
```

**For Swift 2.2 Register For Default Cell From Nib**

```
self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomCellName", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCellIdentifer")
```

**For Swift 3.0 Register For Default Cell From Nib**

```
self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomCellName", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCellName")
```

**Note:** Storyboard created cell is called prototype cell and  have some procedure to register prototype cell like Nib.And Don't forget to set the cell identifier like below.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Swift has once again renamed it to

> tableView.**register**(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"DefaultCell")

Really don't understand why they bothered so much about this particular naming

Answer (score 3):

**Updated for Swift 5**

> Register TableView Cell in viewDidLoad If you are using **Default Cell**

```
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyTableCell")
```

> Register TableView Cell in viewDidLoad If you are using **Custom Nib/XIB Cell**

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyCustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCustomCell")
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use TableViewCell.self to generate the identifier string. It can reduce the typing error.

```
tableView.register(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: MyCell.self))
```

Answer (score 1):

For swift 4

```
self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 and 4.1. making generic methods it is very easy to register and dequeue table cell.

```
       override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                self.tblView.register(CellProfileOther.self) // cell class name
       }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cell: CellProfileOther = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(forIndexPath: indexPath)
                return cell
            }
        extension UITableView {
        func register<T:UITableViewCell>(_: T.Type) where T: ReusableView, T: NibLoadableView {
                let bundle = Bundle(for: T.self)
                let nib = UINib(nibName: T.nibName, bundle: bundle)
                self.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: T.defaultReuseIdentifier)
            }
        func dequeueReusableCell<T:UITableViewCell>(forIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> T where T: ReusableView {
                guard let cell = self.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: T.defaultReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? T else {
                    fatalError("Could not dequeue cell with identifier: \(T.defaultReuseIdentifier)")
                }
                return cell
            }
        }

        protocol ReusableView: class {
            static var defaultReuseIdentifier: String { get }
        }

        protocol NibLoadableView: class {
            static var nibName: String { get }
        }

        extension ReusableView where Self: UIView {
            static var defaultReuseIdentifier: String {
                return String(describing: Self.self)
            }
        }    
        extension NibLoadableView where Self: UIView {
            static var nibName: String {
                return String(describing: Self.self)
            }
        }

   // Here is cell class 
    class CellProfileOther: UITableViewCell, ReusableView, NibLoadableView  {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift 3 refer this. It works!

Inside you viewdidload function

self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "LabelCell")

Answer (score 0):

```
  let cellIds = ["TableViewCell","TableViewCell1", "TableViewCell2", ]
    for cell in cellIds{
          tableView.register(UINib(nibName: cell, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: cell)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -3):

Switching the order in which I called registerNib and registerClass worked for me!

For some reason my app crashed when I had:

...registerNib.....

...registerClass...

But ran fine when I had:

...registerClass...

...registerNib.....

Hope that helps some of you.

Comment: Why are you calling both `registerNib` and `registerClass`? If you `registerNib`, you generally set the class in the NIB, itself.

Comment: Ah, maybe it's possible to link the correct classes without this line but I needed it to run my code and not hit a crash

Comment: My point is that `registerClass` and `registerNib` are mutually exclusive. Only the last called one applies. So, in your first example, `registerClass` replaces `registerNib` and unless you built the cell programmatically, it would crash. In your second example, it will correctly use the NIB, but the `registerClass` call is redundant.