# UiTableView cellForRowAt not return good value and can't scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scrollview

I am a newbie with swift and UITableView, I'm getting datas from a request and I'm trying to display the result on a table view.
I'm getting data very well but my table view doesn't scroll. I know that there is many issues with this problem but I see others answers and I can't solve mine there is the dummy code :

```
 @IBOutlet weak var tav: UITableView!
//Emoji array dynamically created
var emojisArray: [Emoji] = []
{
    didSet {
        tav.reloadData()
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tav.dataSource = self;
    tav.delegate = self;


    //backgroundColor
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 187, green: 222/255, blue: 251, alpha: 1)
    //Url request
    let url = "http://localhost:8888/emoji-api/web/app_dev.php/emojis"
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let requestAPI = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {data, response, error in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error!.localizedDescription) // On indique dans la console ou est le problème dans la requête
        }
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse , httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            print("statusCode devrait être de 200, mais il est de \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("réponse = \(String(describing: response))") // On affiche dans la console si le serveur ne nous renvoit pas un code de 200 qui est le code normal
        }
        // let responseAPI = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        //print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseAPI))") // Affiche dans la console la réponse de l'API
        if error == nil {
            // Ce que vous voulez faire.
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            do {

                // let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
                if let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:Any]]{

                    for item in parsedData {

                        let emoji = Emoji()

                       //Transform unicode on an Emoji
                        let strUnicodeEmoji = String(UnicodeScalar(Int(item["unicode"] as! String, radix: 16)!)!)

                        print(strUnicodeEmoji)
                        emoji.emojiString = strUnicodeEmoji as String;
                        emoji.description =  item["description"] as! String;

                        self.emojisArray.append(emoji)

                    }
                }
            }
            catch   {
                    print("Could not serialise")
                }
            }
        }

    }
    requestAPI.resume()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return emojisArray.count;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell();
 print(emojisArray.count)
    let emoji = emojisArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel?.text = emoji.emojiString;

    return cell;
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
 let defVC = segue.destination as!
    SecondViewController;
    defVC.emojiSelect = sender as! Emoji

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let emojiSelect = emojisArray[indexPath.row];

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondScreen", sender: emojiSelect)
}
```

[image: ScrollView by default]

I don't modify scrollview default value. 
Thank you

Comment: call `tableView.reloadData()` in your completion block in your network call after appending `self.emojisArray`

Comment: This is Swift. Get rid of all of those semicolons. And please do some searching on using table views. Your code for creating a cell in `cellForRowAt` is all wrong. Search on `dequeueReusableCell`

Comment: It's a reflex coming other languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is a performance hit, You are actually reloading UITableView on every element being added on your emojisArray.

```
var emojisArray: [Emoji] = []
{
    didSet {
       tav.reloadData()
     }
}
```

Replace above code with this

```
var emojisArray : [Emoji] = [Emoji]()
```

Reload your UITableView once when you get your datasource ready for e.g..

```
        do {

            // let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
            if let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:Any]]{
            //Creating temporary array for    parsing content
              var tempArr = [Emoji]()
                for item in parsedData {

                    let emoji = Emoji()
                     //Your parsing code
                    tempArr.append(emoji)

                }

              // Reloading of datasource and UITableView will be done in main thread.
               DispatchQueue.main.async {                                      

                    self.emojisArray = tempArr
                   //Reloading tableView once all parsing is complete                        
                    tav.reloadData()
                }
            }
```

Your Tableview must reuse UITableViewCell for better memory utilisation , Instead of allocating a new cell every time.
Replace below code of `cellForRow` method

```
 let cell = UITableViewCell();
```

with

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Your_Reusable_Cell_Identifier", for: indexPath) as! Your_CustomTableViewCell
```

Note: To use reusable Custom UITableViewCell you must register your cell with your  UITableView
See "[UITableView - registerClass with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347406/uitableview-registerclass-with-swift)"

Comment: thank you for your answer but I don't know where can I found/define "Your_CustomTableViewCell" ?

Comment: Hey please go through this https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/ to create your own custom TableViewCell

Comment: Thank you now it's working, I followed your advices and theses two tutorials : https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/ and https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html. Final code http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59c0f56588c199772ebcd59a

Comment: Great to hear this , you achieved what you want , if my answer helps you then please mark as accepted.

Comment: I have gone through your Final code, have suggestion for you please reduce the code written in one long method i.e. viewDidLoad . Break your code in two smaller function for better reading and clarity

Answer (score 1):

Check, your `UITableView` has datasource and delegate connection.

**Dequeue cell**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YOUR_CELL_IDENTIFIER", for: indexPath) as! Your_tableview_cell

    let emoji = emojisArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel?.text = emoji.emojiString;        

    return cell
}
```

**Reload Table view**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        do {

            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
            if let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:Any]]{

                for item in parsedData {

                    ... // your code
                    ...

                }

                YOUR_TABLEVIEW.reloadData(); // You have to reload ur tableview
                                   // in main queue after getting 
                                   //all values in Array
            }
        }
        catch   {
                print("Could not serialise")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not de-queueing your cells.  For more information check out the docs on reusing cells.

```
let cell = UITableViewCell();
```

Should be

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YOUR_CELL_IDENTIFIER", for: indexPath)
```

If you're using Storyboards you'll have to set the Cell Identifier in the Identity Inspector under your cell.

Hope this helps.